# Se pierde el estilo al momento de ingresar login :host ::deep - Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular7

Hola quisiera hacerle una consulta, estaba haciendo cambios de styles a un componente mediante los comandos:

```
:host ::ng-deep
```

ejemplo:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ng-tns-c13-3 .mat-icon-button{
  padding: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: none;
}
```

y todo perfecto cuando actualizaba quedaba como yo queria como esta imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me dado cuenta que cuando ingreso desde login y voy al modulo esos estilos que habia definido en component.scss se pierde y ve asì:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando le doy F5 o actualizar la pagina recien coge los estilos que habia definido con el comando `:host ::ng-deep`

quisiera que al comienzo cuando ingrese ya agarre los estilos que he definido

**en mi archivo component.ts  si esta indicando que component se va utilizar**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-corresponsal',
  templateUrl: './corresponsal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./corresponsal.component.scss'],
  animations: egretAnimations
})
```

Comment: y si usas ese estilo en _global.scss?

Comment: @AndreaJimenez si lo coloco no se modificara en todo los modulos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola buenas el problema era que esa clase era dinamica es decir si entrabas a un modulo tenia el codigo ng-tns-c13-4  pero cuando entrabas de otro tenia ng-tns-c13-5 y sucesivamente.

Investigando encontre que colocando [class*="ng-tns-c"] iba a obtener de forma dinamica todo.
Aunque no se es una forma o habran mejores pero me soluciono el inconveniente.

```
:host ::ng-deep  [class*="ng-tns-c"] .ng-trigger-animate {

 margin-left: 15px; flex: 1 1 100%; box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 20%!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en usar las clases auto generadas como `ng-tns-c13-3`. Los números de esas clases corresponden al orden en que se van creando los componentes. Puede ser que al entrar directamente a la página el componente sea el `c13` pero al entrar desde el login se tomen en cuenta otros componentes y al que haces referencia cambie a `c14` etc.

Puedes usar una clase específica en su lugar:

```
:host ::ng-deep .clase-especifica .mat-icon-button{}
```

Y aplicar esa clase al elemento contenedor del `.mat-icon-button`

```
<elemento class="clase-especifica">
     ...
        <elemento class="mat-icon-button">
```